# Is WSO2 DAS the new name or successor product for WSO2 BAM?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das, wso2-bam

We are evaluating the WSO2 API Manager 1.8.0 (WSO2 AM) together with the WSO2 Business Activity Monitor 2.5.0 (WSO2 BAM). From our support partner Yenlo we got the WSO2 recommendation to use WSO2 BAM 3.0 for new installation, because the changes from BAM 2.5.0 to BAM 3.0.0 are massive.

BAM 3.0 is not released yet (see [the release plan in JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/BAM)). But milestone 4 should be available.

But the only thing I can find is milestone 3 of BAM and milestone 4 of DAS (Data Analytics Server) as announced in this [email](https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@wso2.org/msg43411.html). Also the change log of DAS points to JIRA issues from BAM.

Is DAS the new name for BAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is DAS the new name for BAM?

Yes, with exsisting BAM features + all features of WSO2 CEP are also included additionally in WSO2 DAS.

Some of the content of current BAM also applicable to DAS such as Collect & Store any Type of Business Events, High Performance Data Capture Framework, Pre-Built Data Agents for all WSO2 Products, etc. But since DAS is a complete revamp of old BAM, there are core changes such as analytics engine is now based on spark, and pluggable storage architecture and not cassandra centric (DAS 3.0 will be having RDBMS and hbase connectors).

DAS also includes all WSO2 CEP features, therefore users can do both real time and batch based analysis. Basically it's kind of analytics platform.

The old BAM is mainly focused on batch analysis.

More information can be found in [WSO2 DAS Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/About+DAS). Also DAS would be in the future include Machine Learning Features as well, and it is an another name for whole analytics platform

Comment: DAS would in the future include Machine Learning Features as well, and it is an another name for whole analytics platform.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind as far as I know DAS is not completely backward compatible with BAM. So if you start new from WSO2 AM 1.10.0, best way is to use DAS Version 3, not BAM.