# Sending log to BAM by using logevent

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

I am testing ESB 4.9.0 and BAM 2.5.0, and tried to follow this document https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon442/Publishing+Logs+to+BAM to publish ESB logs to BAM, but it reported an ERROR when initiate ESB instance.

```
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.wso2.carbon.logging.service.appende
r.LogEventAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.logging.service.appender.LogEventAppender cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.logging_4.4.1
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:327)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:124)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:785)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
        at com.atomikos.logging.Slf4jLogger.<init>(Slf4jLogger.java:8)
        at com.atomikos.logging.Slf4JLoggerFactoryDelegate.createLogger(Slf4JLoggerFactoryDelegate.java:7)
        at com.atomikos.logging.LoggerFactory.createLogger(LoggerFactory.java:12)
        at com.atomikos.logging.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:52)
        at com.atomikos.transactions.internal.AtomikosActivator.<clinit>(AtomikosActivator.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "LOGEVENT".log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.wso2.carbon.logging.service.appende
r.LogEventAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.logging.service.appender.LogEventAppender cannot be found by org.wso2.carbon.logging_4.4.1
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:327)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:124)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:785)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
        at com.atomikos.logging.Slf4jLogger.<init>(Slf4jLogger.java:8)
        at com.atomikos.logging.Slf4JLoggerFactoryDelegate.createLogger(Slf4JLoggerFactoryDelegate.java:7)
        at com.atomikos.logging.LoggerFactory.createLogger(LoggerFactory.java:12)
        at com.atomikos.logging.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:52)
        at com.atomikos.transactions.internal.AtomikosActivator.<clinit>(AtomikosActivator.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "LOGEVENT".
```

The log4j LOGEVENT configuration:

```
# LOGEVENT is set to be a LogEventAppender using a PatternLayout to send logs to LOGEVENT 
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT=org.wso2.carbon.logging.service.appender.LogEventAppender
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.url=tcp://10.100.78.135:7612
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.columnList=%T,%S,%H,%A,%d,%c,%p,%m,%I,%Stacktrace
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.userName=admin
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.password=admin
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.processingLimit=1000
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.maxTolerableConsecutiveFailure=20
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.LOGEVENT.streamDef=BAM_LOG_STREAM
```

When I tried to find the logeventappender in org.wso2.carbon.logging.service_4.4.7.jar, it cannot be find. This appender can be find in org.wso2.carbon.logging.service_4.2.0.jar from the previously released ESB 4.8.1.

If this function is still in use in 4.9.0, could anyone help me set it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature will no longer supported with ESB 4.9.0 and BAM 2.5.0. Because both are depends on two different carbon version.

ESB 4.9.0 depends on carbon 4.4.0 and BAM 2.5.0 depends on 4.2.0.

WSO2 now depricated BAM and introduced a new product called [Data Analytics Server](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/About+DAS), which is a [revamp of old BAM with more additional features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823576/is-wso2-das-the-new-name-or-successor-product-for-wso2-bam).

You may use the [Logging Agent](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Logging) feature of DAS 3.0.0 with ESB 4.9.0

Comment: The provided "Logging Agent" is not an alternative - this does not enable to monitor a log withing BAM/DAS of another product. But when you look at the Documentation of Carbon 4.4 - this feature is still available, but the class seem to be missing: https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon442/Publishing+Logs+to+BAM